# Speed up the DirectX game - how else can I boost the fps with typical triangle drawing?

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, directx11, optimization

I am writing my own c++/DirectX engine. I've made the basic framework and here comes the time for optimizations.

I don't want to focus on optimizing the resources themselves right now (meshes, textures) or on instancing. I've also **commented out** shadows and normal mapping for that test. **So it's just a "flat" problem of "how to speed up rendering that vertices?"**.

**The meshes are fully static, loaded from files** (no terrain generation involved).

I just have about 120.000 triangles with textures on scene (one shader, few models). And on my laptop I get about 20-40fps. I was able to increase fps with vsync and back-face a bit (note that camera is rotating and fps falls when all 120.000 triangles are within its range):
[image]

Still, other engines (Unity, Unreal) can render the same meshes faster on the same hardware (and Unreal does it even faster then Unity which still is better then my DirecX11/c++ implementation). **How they do that?** I know there are many "pro programmers" behind that engines, but they are no magicians. And **some** solutions should be possible to apply in my engine too (vsync was easy to apply yet it gave me a nice speed boost).

I use DirectX 11, c++. I use Visual Studio if it's important. There is very little logic involved in application, no physics, no searches etc. that could slow down the render loop.

**So far I made just few optimizations:**

1. Dynamic/static vertex buffers where they are needed. Index buffer.
2. Back-face culling.
3. V-SYNC (more about removing bugs but also helped with fps a bit).
4. Near/far clipping.
5. Compressing textures into single texture atlas (I've not done it yet, but I am aware of that technique).
6. Lowering the AA (e.g. MSAA) and resolution (but it has an big impact on render quality).

I know my hardware is capable of rendering such amount of triangles. **But how to help it?** My problem is that **I don't know all the tricks & methods that can be used here**.

If any part of the source code would be useful, just comment me (I'm not sure which parts should I post and I don't want to paste meaningless code listings). I will post the results of fps increase/decrease as I manage to incorporate new optimizations.

Comment: I can't tell much about direct3d since i'm using opengl but you'll need to find out *where* exactly the bottleneck is. As far as i know, Visual Studio has its own graphics debugger and profiler, i've seen podcasts from microsoft  where they use this profiler and get a nice timeline which shows, what happens when and how long it takes.

Comment: Have you played with frustum culling? Cull out shapes that aren't in the view. DirectX automatically culls, but it is per triangle. It's a lot more efficient to cull out entire batches. It's even more efficient if you work on a scene graph. hierarchically culling them. I do not believe this is your bottleneck though.

Comment: For Direct3D on Windows, the key performance question is how many individual Draw batches you are submitting? This directly drives a lot of the CPU and kernel overhead. Good tools to try: VS 2013/2015 Graphics Diagnostics, [GPUView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570133.aspx), [Intel GPA](http://www.intel.com/software/gpa), [NVIDIA nSight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition), and/or [AMD GPU PerfStudio](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-perfstudio/).

Comment: Thank you all for the comments :) I will definitely use frustum culling and look into draw batches (the less the better? or above some batch size, it's better to split it?). I have one concern - when I profile the program, won't I end up in local minimum (the optimization for my specific hardware which may not work on other PC with e.g. different GPU/CPU "performance proportion")?

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8228/BatchBatchBatch.pdf Read up on what exactly a batch is. I imagine you are using batches already. I suggest downloading Nvidia Nsight (a graphics debugger) and poking around with it for a bit. Very nice tool.